# For the divisor function is $d(n^2)$ related to $d(n)$ knowing also n?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum

The divisor function d(n) is defined as *'the number of positive divisors of n (including 1 and n)'* according to Underwood Dudley.

Is the divisor function $d(n^2)$ related to $d(n)$?

for example

d(10)=4  and $d(10^2)$=9
or d(14)=4 and $d(14^2)=9$

So can one find the $d(n^2)$ from knowing only d(n) and n through some relation or function?

Has any work been done on this problem?

Comment: Just to be clear, $d$ doesn't count the number itself, so for any prime it gives $1$?

Comment: @Arthur okay thanks I'll remove 1 from each

Comment: You should get $d(n^2) = 2^k d(n)$, where $k$ is the number of "distinct" primes in $n$

Comment: @rsadhvika so for n=100 $2^2*2=8$?

Comment: I don't understand that function $d$.

Comment: Nvm. The expression doesn't look to simplify.. Look up @Arthur 's answer..

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Obviously if you know $n$ you can compute $d(n^2)$ (however you are defining it).  What are you asking?

Comment: @lulu looks the OP wants to express $d(n^2)$ as a function $d(n)$ with out working prime factorization of $n$ or $n^2$

Comment: @lulu yes its hard to explain. if I know n and d(n) say n=10 and d(10)=2 from this information is d(n^2) related as  rsadhvika suggests?

Comment: But the posted solutions show that you need some information regarding the prime factorization of $n$.  Not sure what you are hoping for.

Comment: If you want to experiment, use [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sigma_0(10)).  The function $\sigma_0(n)$ is the usual divisor function (i.e. the number of divisors).  Whatever your $d(n)$ is you can write it in terms of $\sigma_0$.  WA can compute this for quite large integers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to get from the value of $d(n)$ to the value of $d(n^2)$ without involving $n$. For instance, we have $d(6)=d(8)=3$, but $d(36)=8$ while $d(64)=6$.

Your divisor function is closely related to prime factorisations. If
$$
n=2^{e_2}\cdot3^{e_3}\cdot5^{e_5}\cdots
$$
(where most of the $e_k$ are $0$), then
$$
d(n)=(e_2+1)(e_3+1)(e_5+1)\cdots-1
$$
Squaring $n$ doubles all the $e_k$. For the example above, we have
$$
d(6)=(1+1)(1+1)-1=3
d(8)=(3+1)-1=3\\
d(36)=(2+1)(2+1)-1\\
d(64)=(6+1)-1=6
$$
So for each way you can write $d(n)+1$ as a product of natural numbers greater than $1$, there is a different value to $d(n^2)$.

Comment: my question had some ambiguity when you say "There is no direct way to get from the value of d(n) to the value of d(n2) without involving n" does this change if one knows n as I had intended the question to be?

Comment: @onepound If we know $n$, then we may calculate $d(n^2)$ without involving $d(n)$. I don't know a way to calculate $d(n^2)$ from $n$ and $d(n)$ which involves $d(n)$ in any crucial way, but there may be one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}p_i^{a_i},\,a_i>0$ so $d(n)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}(1+a_i)$. Then $n^2=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}p_i^{2a_i}$ so $d(n^2)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}(1+2a_i)$ which cannot be expressed purely in terms of $d(n)$.

Comment: okay so the answer is no given your proof.

Comment: @onepound  No, he gives the answer to your question.  The answer is "no" and he proved it.

Comment: @B. Goddard yes purely in terms of d(n) it cannot be done that was obvious empirically in the example I gave above I meant including n too.